# Pandas timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

I'd like to group my data per day and calculate the daily mean of the sentiment.

I have problem with the **pandas** dataframe because I am not able to transform my date column in *datestamp* to use the `groupby()` function. Here is my data sample:

```
   sentiment              date
0  1  2018-01-01 07:37:07+00:00
1  0  2018-02-12 06:57:27+00:00
2  -1  2018-09-18 06:23:07+00:00
3  1 2018-09-18 07:23:10+00:00
4  0  2018-02-12 06:21:08+00:00
```

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
sentiment       5 non-null int64
date    5 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 76.0+ bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) - it create full `DatatimeIndex`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = df.resample('D',on='date')['sentiment'].mean()
#if want remove NaNs rows
df1 = df.resample('D',on='date')['sentiment'].mean().dropna()
```

Or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `mean` with [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)s or [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove times:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['sentiment'].mean()
#DatetimeIndex in output
df2 = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('d'))['sentiment'].mean()
```